# Getting Error While uploading Video to YouTube using its API

Tags: c#, youtube-api

I have created API key and used it as developer key. I'm getting this error while uploading video to YouTube:

```
Google.GData.Client.GDataRequestException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Execution of request failed: https://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads
  Source=Google.GData.Client
  ResponseString=<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><errors><error><domain>yt:validation</domain><code>invalid_value</code><location type='xpath'>media:group/media:category[@scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat']/text()</location></error></errors>
  StackTrace:
       at Google.GData.Client.GDataRequest.Execute()
       at Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute(Int32 retryCounter)
       at Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute()
       at Google.GData.Client.MediaService.EntrySend(Uri feedUri, AtomBase baseEntry, GDataRequestType type, AsyncSendData data)
       at Google.GData.Client.Service.Insert(Uri feedUri, AtomEntry newEntry, AsyncSendData data)
       at Google.GData.Client.Service.Insert[TEntry](Uri feedUri, TEntry entry)
       at Google.GData.YouTube.YouTubeService.Upload(String userName, YouTubeEntry entry)
       at Google.YouTube.YouTubeRequest.Upload(String userName, Video v)
       at Google.YouTube.YouTubeRequest.Upload(Video v)
       at WebApplication1.WebForm2.UploadVideoToYoutube() in c:\Users\Ajay.Kumar\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\WebForm2.aspx.cs:line 87
       at WebApplication1.WebForm2.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Ajay.Kumar\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\WebForm2.aspx.cs:line 21
       at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  InnerException: System.Net.WebException
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
       Source=System
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at Google.GData.Client.GDataRequest.Execute()
       InnerException:
```

I'm using below code to upload video and using Developer key as API key(Browser)

```
YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("My Channel", devKey, username, password) { Timeout = -1 };
             YouTubeRequest  request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
                Video newVideo = new Video();

                newVideo.Title = Title;
                newVideo.Description = Description;
                // newVideo.Private = true;
                newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;

                newVideo.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource(FilePath, "video/mp4");
                Video CreateVideo = request.Upload(newVideo);
```

Comment: Did you try reading the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors)?

Comment: I'm confusing with the developer key. Is it API key?